# Converting a named aggregate prior to pandas/python3

Tags: python, pandas

For the below:

```
summary_df = (df
    .groupby(['provider', 'master_id'])
    .agg(
        content_type_id             =('content_type_id', 'first'),
        title                       =('title', 'first'),
        release_year                =('release_year', 'first'), ...
        subs                        =('burned_in_sub_language', lambda x: str(sorted(i.lower() for i in x.dropna().unique())))
      )
    .reset_index()
)
```

What would be the proper way to do this before named aggregates were introduced, including the aliasing of columns?

Comment: You can pass as a `dict` like `agg({"content_type_id":"first", "title:"first"...}`

Comment: @HenryYik ok, but how do you do the renames then? Or do you need a separate/chained method to do that part? For example, see how `burned_in_sub_language` goes to `sub` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Henry Yik, use [.agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) followed by [.rename()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). 
For example:

```
summary_df = (df
    .groupby(['provider', 'master_id'])
    .agg({'content_type_id':'first', 'title': 'first',})
    .rename(columns={
        'content_type_id': 'something else', 
        'title': 'changed_name',})
)
```

Comment: I see -- so is the "new" way just a succinct way of combining those two methods?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 yeah, I myself am quite happy about it, for me it just saves extra typing with it, so i use the new way if I need to rename the columns, which is most of the time